# Authenticate user with FormDigest via CSOM/REST

Tags: client-object-model, rest, authentication

Our SharePoint 2013 farm is using Windows Authentication and exposed to the Internet.  We have a webparts contains javascript AJAX call to another server with a different hostname.

**Intranet**: intranet.northwind.com 
**API**: api.northwind.com

Obviously we can't turn on IIS Windows Authentication for our API server, otherwise we can't call it from javascript loading from Intranet page without exposing any user credentials.

Can I use the SharePoint FormDigest as the token to call something via CSOM or REST inside our API application to authenticate a user?  There is no problem passing the X-FormDigest value across our API application, it just that I don't know if there any method to use this token to authenticate a user.

Answer (score 1):

You hardly can authenticate with X-FormDigest, even if that part is mandatory for POST methods.

You really need the user token and add a Bearer Header to your HTTP request

```
headers: {
        ...
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + UserOrAppToken
        ...
    },
```

If you're not able to get user token, you can use the AppOnly token with ClientID and ClientSecret, but you need one token for all requests.
[More info about AppOnly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/02/23/sharepoint-2013-app-only-policy-made-easy.aspx)

Mind my answer if you did use an equivalent of next sample in JavaScript.

```
clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += delegate(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Bearer {0}", CurrentProperties.Token);
};
```